Using/Installing Downloaded Julia Packages Without Github Access
We're looking to use a Julia (v1.10) program at work, but IT blocks Github on our network. We got them to download the source code and (several dozen) dependencies themselves from Github in package form and send them to us.  I extracted the packages, renamed the folders to remove the *.jl-master extension, and appended the dependency file path to the LOAD_PATH environment variable, but I'm now having trouble actually using the packages, as Julia tries to clone a registry from JuliaRegistries/General.git when running 'using ', which fails due to Github again being blocked. Is there a way to install or otherwise use source code from external packages completely offline that bypasses the registry issue?
There have been a few related posts suggesting having the program installed presumably by IT and have them send us the ~/.julia file containing the installation, or to use a container, but these fixes still go through IT, which is a lengthy approval process, and I'm not sure if the registry issue would still occur. There is also a related post which suggests placing the packages in compiled form into a file path that is appended to the LOAD_PATH, but I believe that would require another package (PackageCompiler.jl) to compile the source code, which may run into the same registry issue assuming I can get it downloaded from IT. Maybe I can resolve the dependencies with a ton of include/using statements, although the building/compiling of dependencies may still be an issue.

you might want to try the julia forum as well. if you have already, you should crosslink to and from there.

The limiting factor may be different, but I would think that the solution posted here ( https://discourse.julialang.org/t/offline-installation-of-julia-packages/20083 ) may be useful. This thread is trying to get around having no internet access at all on a device, and some solutions require a secondary device (IT, in your case) to either build in a specific way or to create a sysimage (which would be my first thought).

Would Pkg.offline(true) work for you? For this you just need to have a configured JULIA_DEPOT_PATH folder (e.g. ~/.julia) that you can copy across machine and use as needed to create virtual envs for your projects without reaching to the package repo
